# Palindromes on Keypad and divisibility by $111$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The integers 1 through 9 are arranged as follows on a rectangular keypad:

$\begin{array}{c c c}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}$

Consider the 6-digit palindromes formed by going back and forth across a diagonal, row, or column of the grid. (ex: 123321, 159951, 357753, 456654, ...).

Why are all these numbers divisible by 111? In other words, what property of these numbers makes them divisible by 111? I've tried casework on whether the number is formed on a row, diagonal, or column, but haven't gotten anywhere.

In addition, can we generalize the result (keypads with different combinations of numbers that still have the above property)?

Comment: Your grid is not drawn clearly. It doesn't seem rectangular.

Comment: For base $b$, any palindrome with $2n$ digits s divisible by $b+1$. If the digits are an arithmetic progression, the number is divisible by $\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}$. Here, those values (with $b=10$ and $n=3$) are 11 and 111. See my answer for details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is on SUMAC 2016 (stanford summer math camp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the keypad :

$$\begin{array}{c c c}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}$$

Take a look at rows, columns and diagonals. What do they have in common? If you take any 3 numbers in a row, columns or diagonal, say $a\, b\, c$, then $b-a=c-b$. Let's call this difference $\epsilon:=b-a=c-b$.

Now take any palindrome formed with a column, row or diagonal, its general form is

$$P=10^5a+10^4b+10^3c+10^2c+10b+a$$
Replace $b=a+\epsilon$ and $c=a+2\epsilon$
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P&=&10^5a+10^4(a+\epsilon)+10^3(a+2\epsilon)+10^2(a+2\epsilon)+10(a+\epsilon)+a\\
&=&a(10^5+10^4+10^3+10^2+10+1)+\epsilon(10^4+2\cdot 10^3+2\cdot 10^2+10)\\
&=&111111a+12210\epsilon\\
&=&11\cdot 111\cdot 91\cdot a + 11\cdot 111\cdot 10\cdot \epsilon
\end{array}$$

Both the $a$ term and the $\epsilon$ term are divisible by $111$ and $11$.

Note: $\epsilon$ can be positive or negative or even null. It can even work for $a\,b\,c$ that aren't in the keypad.

Comment: Cool! How would I generalize this result for any keypad?

Comment: Well, as long as you build a keypad that follows the property that for any $a\,b\,c$-row, column or diagonal, you have $b-a=c-b$ and $0\leq a,b,c\leq 9$

Answer (score 2):

Consider a number in base $10$ with digits $abccba$, where $b-a=c-b>0$ (note that this is the case in all your examples).  Letting $d=b-a=c-b$, the number can be written in terms of digits as
$$aaaaaa+0dddd0+00dd00=aaaaaa+0ddd00+00ddd0\ ,$$
which in "proper" notation is
$$111111a+11100d+1110d=111(1001a+110d)\ ,$$
a multiple of $111$.

**Comment**.  The same will work if $d<0$, though the "digits" will look a bit crazy.  So for example $321123$ is also a multiple of $111$.

Comment: Nice. I looked at the general case, and did not pick up the special cases actually used.

Answer (score 0):

I show at the end
that, for any base $b$
and $2n$ palindromic 
 base $b$ digits
that the number is divisible by $b+1$.

If the digits
are in arithmetic progression,
as all the examples are,
I will also show that
the number is
divisible by
$\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}
$.

For this examples
(base 10, $n=3$),
the numbers are divisible by
11x 111
=1221
=3x11x37.

First,
*any* palindromic number.

All these numbers
are of the form

$\begin{array}\\
10^5a+10^4b+10^3c+10^2c+10b+a
&=a(10^5+1)+b(10^4+10)+c(10^3+10^2)\\
&=a(10^5+1)+b(10^4+10)+c(10^3+10^2)\\
&=a(10^5+1)+10b(10^3+1)+100c(10+1)\\
&=11a(10^4-10^3+10^2-10^1+1)+10\cdot 11b(10^2-10+1)+100\cdot 11c\\
&=11(a(10^4-10^3+10^2-10^1+1)+10b(10^2-10+1)+100c)\\
\end{array}
$

So these are all divisible by 11
(not 111).

In general,
if there are
$2n$ digits
of
$(a_k)_{k=1}^n$
and then reversed
in base $b$,
the sum is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b^{2n-k}+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b^{k-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (b^{2n-k}+b^{k-1})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b^{k-1}(b^{2n-2k+1}+1)\\
\end{array}
$

Each term is divisible
by $b+1$
because
$b^{2m+1}+1
=(b+1)\sum_{j=0}^{2m} (-1)^j b^j
$.

Carrying this out
further so see if
any other factors show up,
the sum is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b^{k-1}(b^{2n-2k+1}+1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b^{k-1}(b+1)\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2k} (-1)^j b^j\\
&=(b+1)\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2k} (-1)^j b^j\\
&=(b+1)\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-\lfloor j/2\rfloor} a_k b^{k-1} (-1)^j b^j
\quad\text{(see (*) below)}\\
&=(b+1)\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^j b^j\sum_{k=1}^{n-\lfloor j/2\rfloor} a_k b^{k-1} \\
&=(b+1)\sum_{j=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^j b^jA_{n-\lfloor j/2\rfloor}
\quad\text{where }A_m=\sum_{k=1}^{m} a_k b^{k-1} \\
\end{array}
$

I don't see any other
factors immediately.

But see below!!

(*)
$j \le 2n-2k
\implies 2k \le 2n-j
$

Then,
with the digits
being in
arithmetic progression.

Warning:
Messy algebra ahead!

Aha!
As David noticed,
the $a_k$ are in
arithmetic progression.
I will see what happens
in this case.

Assume
$a_k
=a+kd
$.

Then the sum is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (b^{2n-k}+b^{k-1})
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (a+kd) (b^{2n-k}+b^{k-1})\\
&=a\sum_{k=1}^n (b^{2n-k}+b^{k-1})
+d\sum_{k=1}^n k (b^{2n-k}+b^{k-1})
\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n (b^{2n-k}+b^{k-1})
&=\sum_{k=1}^n b^{2n-k}+\sum_{k=1}^n b^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} b^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b^{k}\\
&=b^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b^{k}\\
&=(b^n+1)\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Similarly,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k (b^{2n-k}+b^{k-1})
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k b^{2n-k}+\sum_{k=1}^n kb^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} (2n-k) b^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} kb^{k-1}\\
&=b^n\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} (2n-k) b^{k-n}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} kb^{k-1}\\
&=b^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k) b^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} kb^{k-1}\\
&=b^n(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} n b^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k b^{k})+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} kb^{k-1}\\
&=nb^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  b^{k}-(b^n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k b^{k})\\
&=nb^n\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}
-(b^n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k b^{k}\\
&=nb^n\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}
-(b^n-1)\frac{(b^{n+1}-1)-(b-1)(nb^n+1)}{(b-1)^2}
\quad\text{(see }(**)\text{ below)}\\
&=(b^n-1)\left(\frac{nb^n}{b-1}
-\frac{(b^{n+1}-1)-(b-1)(nb^n+1)}{(b-1)^2}\right)\\
&=(b^n-1)\left(\frac{nb^n(b-1)-((b^{n+1}-1)-(b-1)(nb^n+1))}{(b-1)^2}\right)\\
&=(b^n-1)\left(\frac{(b-1)(nb^n+nb^n+1))
-(b^{n+1}-1)}{(b-1)^2}\right)\\
&=(b^n-1)\left(\frac{(b-1)(2nb^n+1))
-(b^{n+1}-1)}{(b-1)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{(b^n-1)(b-1)(2nb^n+1))
-(b^n-1)(b^{n+1}-1)}{(b-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{(b^n-1)(b-1)(2nb^n+1))
}{(b-1)^2}
-\frac{(b^n-1)(b^{n+1}-1)}{(b-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{(b^n-1)(2nb^n+1))
}{b-1}
-\frac{(b^n-1)(b^{n+1}-1)}{(b-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}\left(2nb^n+1
-\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}
$
divides all these terms,
so it divides
the whole sum.

$(**)$
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)x^k
=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kx^k
&=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}
-\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{(1-x^{n+1})-(1-x)((n+1)x^n+(1-x^n)}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{(1-x^{n+1})-(1-x)(nx^n+1)}{(1-x)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: But they *are* divisible by 111.

Comment: They are all divisible by 1221 = 11*111

Comment: add the restriction that $a_{n+1} - a_{i} = a_{n+1 + i} - a_{n+1}$ and you'll see more factors.

Comment: fleablood, could you elaborate a bit more on that? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: fleablood is right. See my modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see  $abccba$.  $k=  c - b = b - a = \pm3,2,$ or $4$.

So $abccba = 111111*b \pm (100001 - 1100)k = 111111*b \pm (98901)k = 111(1001*b + 891k)$.

So ... that's that.

By the way.  11 also divides it so 1221 divides them.  This will be true of any six digit palindrome where to the three unique digits average to the second digit.